# Different ways of using a comparator in C++

Tags: c++, struct, boolean, comparator

I saw two different answers in Leetcode using comparators:

1. why is the first `Comp` function defined outside of the class? Even when I bring `Comp` into the class, the Leetcode fails.
2. How are you able to use `Comp` with out the `()`?
3. How come I often see compare in structs?

```
bool Comp(const string& a, const string& b) {
    ...
}

class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> reorderLogFiles(vector<string>& logs) {
        stable_sort(logs.begin(), logs.end(), Comp);
        // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ here
        return logs;
    }
};
```

and then

```
struct CompareLogs
{
    bool operator() (const string& str1, const string& str2)
    {
        ...
    }
};

vector<string> reorderLogFiles(vector<string>& logs) {
    sort(letter_logs.begin(), letter_logs.end(), CompareLogs());
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ and here       
    return letter_logs;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to read up on function pointers and functors

Comment: A non-static function inside a class (aka a method) has an implicit parameter `this` that enables it to access the class members. This makes it different from a regular function. You can't mix and match functions and methods, they're just different.

Comment: @Alan, i looked at functors. so the struct Comparelogs is a functor. what is the top scenario considered?

Comment: A function pointer

Comment: A functor is typically used when *state* information has to be carried between multiple invocations. In modern C++, a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) can replace both scenerios. A non-capturing lambda is like a standalone function, and a capturing lambda is like a functor.

Answer (score 1):

> why is the first Comp function defined outside of the class?

As long as your self-defined function fulfills the expected parameters, you can place it inside or outside the class.

> Even when I bring Comp into the class, the Leetcode fails.

You need to add `static` to make it class-independent:

```
class Solution
{
public:

    static bool Comp(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
    {
    }

    std::vector<std::string> reorderLogFiles(std::vector<std::string>& logs)
    {
        std::stable_sort(logs.begin(), logs.end(), Comp);
        return logs;
    }
};
```

> How come I often see compare in structs?

I do not see any advantage here.

Finally, one advice: use `std::` prefix, do not omit it. You will avoid future problems.